Shiny App server code not receiving input variables
I'm trying to create a UI with two dropdown fields referencing data frames in the global environment--mon and apps. I'm using selectizeInput to do this.  I click an actionButton (ID="do") to send the input variables to the server.
I added a browser statement to step through the server code, but it never steps through observeEvent block, and so it doesn't pick any input variables before jumping into the proc function.
Hoping someone can help spot what I'm doing wrong.
#shiny app

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Utilization"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(    
      
      width = 2,
      p("Select a month and application, then click Submit"),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "month", label = NULL, choices = mon$Month, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, options = NULL),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "apps", label = NULL, choices = apps$Apps, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, options = NULL),
      actionButton("do", "Submit")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot", height = '900px')
    )
    
  )
  
)




server <- function(input, output) {
  
  browser()
  
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    
    x1 <- input$mon
    x2 <- input$apps
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      
      proc(x1, x2)
      
      })
    
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)







#code preceding shiny app

#access source file

path = "I:\\PMO\\EPIC TRAINING\\Epic Training\\2024\\Sustainable Jan 2024  - Dec 2024.xlsx"

d1 <- read_excel(path, sheet = "Staff - Courses", col_names = TRUE)



#extract trainers and applications and remove NAs
trapp <- d1[c(2:5)]
trapp <- trapp[rowSums(is.na(trapp)) != ncol(trapp), ]
rm(d1)


#extract worksheet tab names and create data frames

d1sheets <- as.data.frame(excel_sheets(path = path))
d1sheets <- as.data.frame(d1sheets[c(1:12),])  # list of months
colnames(d1sheets) <- c("Month")

dt <- Sys.Date()
cm <- as.numeric(format(dt,'%m'))
lm <- cm - 1
nm <- cm + 1

dflm <- read_excel(path, sheet = lm, skip = 1)
dfcm <- read_excel(path, sheet = cm, skip = 1)
dfnm <- read_excel(path, sheet = nm, skip = 1)


#clean up data frames

cleandf <- function(x) {
  x <- x[c(1:11)]
  x <- subset(x, select = -c(3, 5:8) )
  
  x %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, str_trim)
}

dflm <- cleandf(dflm)
dfcm <- cleandf(dfcm)
dfnm <- cleandf(dfnm)

mon <- as.data.frame(d1sheets[c(lm,cm,nm),])
colnames(mon) <- c("Month")
rm(d1sheets)




#create list of applications

applist <- trapp[2]
applist <- as.data.frame(unique(applist))
applist <- applist[order(applist$`Application 1`),, drop=FALSE]
colnames(applist) <-  c("Apps")
apps <- applist
rownames(apps) = NULL
rm(applist)




proc <- function (mx, apps) {
  
  #display ui for user to select application from apps data frame. Pass to the aptr1-3 variables 
  
  colnames(trapp) <-  c("Trainer","App1","App2","App3")
  
  aptr1 <- filter(trapp, App1 == apps)  #selected app based on user input
  aptr2 <- filter(trapp, App2 == apps)
  aptr3 <- filter(trapp, App3 == apps)
  
  ap1 <- aptr1[1]
  ap2 <- aptr2[1]
  ap3 <- aptr3[1]
  
  apptrainer <- rbind(ap1, ap2, ap3)
  apptrainer %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, str_trim)
  
  rm(aptr1, aptr2, aptr3, ap1, ap2, ap3)
  
  apptrainer <- as.data.frame(unique(apptrainer))
  apptrainer <- apptrainer[order(apptrainer$Trainer),, drop=FALSE]
  
  
  
  #selected schedule from user selected month
  
  #browser()
  
  if (mx == mon[1,1]) {
    schedule <- dflm
  }
  
  if (mx == mon[2,1]) {
    schedule <- dfcm
  }
  
  if (mx == mon[3,1]) {
    schedule <- dfnm
  }
  
  #search for app trainers in schedule
  #loop through app trainer 
  
  cnt1 <- nrow(apptrainer)
  cnt2 <- nrow(schedule)
  
  buildtab <- function(x) {
    
    df <- NULL
    
    df <- data.frame(Characters=character(),
                     Characters=character(),
                     Ints=integer(),
                     Ints=integer(),
                     Characters=character()
    )
    
    colnames(df) <- c("Application","Course","Date","Duration","Trainer")
    
    p = 1
    
    for(i in 1:cnt1) {
      
      h <- apptrainer[i,]
      
      for(n in 1:cnt2) {
        
        if (x == 1) {
          j <- schedule$Trainer1[n]
          
        } else {
          j <- schedule$`Trainer 2`[n]
        }
        
        if ( h == j & !is.na(j) ) {
          
          app <- schedule$Application[n]
          course <- schedule$Name[n]
          course_date <- as.numeric(schedule$`Session Date`[n])
          course_date <- as.Date(course_date, origin = "1899-12-30")
          course_date <- format(as.Date(course_date, "%m/%d/%y"))
          duration <- schedule$Hours[n]
          
          df[p,1] <- app
          df[p,2] <- course
          df[p,3] <- course_date
          df[p,4] <- as.numeric(duration)
          df[p,5] <- j
          
          if (x == 1) {
            df1 <<- rbind(df)
            
          } else {
            df2 <<- rbind(df)
          }
          
          p = p + 1
          
        }
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
  buildtab(1)
  buildtab(2)
  
  df <- rbind(df1, df2)
  
  h <- df %>% arrange(Trainer, Application)
  h  <- aggregate(Duration ~ Trainer + Application, h, sum)
  h1 <- paste("Trainer Classroom Hours by Application", ": ", mx)
  s <- ggplot(h, aes(x=Trainer, y = Duration, fill = Application))
  
  
  utilchart <- s + geom_bar(stat='identity') + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,2),"cm"), text = element_text(size=11), axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) + 
    ggtitle(h1) + 
    xlab("Trainers") + 
    ylab("Hours") +
    labs(fill = "Course")
  
  #print(utilchart)
  
}






Your code is not reproducible. Not sure what proc() is supposed to do and there is no input data. However, please check the following (using dummy data):
mon <- list(Month = month.name)
apps <- list(Apps = paste0("app_", letters))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Utilization"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(    
      width = 2,
      p("Select a month and application, then click Submit"),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "month", label = NULL, choices = mon$Month, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, options = NULL),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "apps", label = NULL, choices = apps$Apps, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, options = NULL),
      actionButton("do", "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot", height = '900px')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1, 1, main = input$mon, sub = input$apps)
  }) |> bindEvent(input$do)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Thanks for your feedback @ismirsehregal. I added the remaining application code. The plot displays fine, so everything up to the shiny app is working well.

Just ran your updated code @ismirsehregal and it worked great! Thank you. If you don't mind, can you elaborate on this statement "|> bindEvent(input$do)", particularly the |> at the beginning?

Please see ?bindEvent and this SO post.
